# Check if input or textarea tags has been selected

Tags: javascript, css, coldfusion

**Problem:** I would like to determine if the user has either manually entered or has selected. If the user has entered manually a value, I would like a particular hidden tr tag to appear. If the user selects the magnifying glass, a different pop up box appears where the user has the option to select a value and displays the value. So if the user does either or, to show only the hidden tag

So currently, I have the following css to hide particular tr tags:

```
#display{display:none;}
#display1{display:none;}
```

I have these id's on the following tags. The following code is done in Coldfusion which I followed a tutorial online:

```
<tr id="display">
      <td valign="top"><input name="txtHealthPlan" value="<cfoutput>#strHealthPlan#</cfoutput>" size="30" style="border:none;background-color:transparent;" readonly> </td>
      <td><textarea class="a" name="txtOPTDesc" cols="25" rows="2" id="txtOPTDesc" readonly ><cfoutput>#strOPTDesc#</cfoutput></textarea></td>

      </tr>
      <cfif #strsflag# Neq 1>
       <cfquery name="CONTRACTS" datasource="OCE">
         select CODE, NAME from CONTRACTS
            where CODE = '#SearchName#'

        </cfquery>

        <cfquery name="Description" datasource="OCE">
          select DESC from BM_OPT_MASTER
          where CODE = '#SearchName#'
          and OPT = '#strOPT#'

        </cfquery>

  <tr id="display1">
  <td valign="top" style="background:white;"><input id = "display4" name="txtPlannew" value="<cfoutput>#CONTRACTS.NAME#</cfoutput>" size="30" style="border:none;background-color:transparent;" readonly> </td>
   <td style="background:white;"><textarea  id = "display5" class="a" name="txtOPTDescnew" cols="25" rows="2" id="txtOPTDescnew" readonly ><cfoutput>#OPTDescription.OPTDesc#</cfoutput></textarea>

      </td>
      </tr></cfif>
```

And the following is the pop up that user is redirected when the click on the magnifying glass to select a value

```
 <p align="center">

 <strong>Health Plan</strong> &nbsp;&nbsp; <!---<input type="hidden" name="txtSearch" value="<cfoutput>#SearchName#</cfoutput>" size="20">  ---><!---&nbsp;&nbsp;OPT&nbsp;&nbsp;<input class="a" name="txtOPT" size="15" 
     value="<cfoutput>#strOPT#</cfoutput>">---> 

     <select name="HPlanDrop" id="HPlanDrop" class="bb">
                                 <option value=""></option>
                                 <cfoutput query="HPCONTRACTS"> 
                                  <option value="#HPCODE#">#HPCODE#&nbsp;-&nbsp;&nbsp;#HPNAME#</option>

                                </cfoutput> 
                                </select>
     &nbsp;&nbsp;
  <input type="button" class="buttona" onClick="SubmitMe()" value="Search">
  <!---&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <input type="button" value=" Clear " onClick="ClearForm()">--->
    </p>
```

And I have the following listener to check if the user has manually entered a value or has clicked on a value.

```
var display = document.getElementById["display"].addEventListener("input", checkTextField);
    var display1 = document.getElementByClassName["display1"].addEventListener("click", checkTextField);
    function checkTextField() {
        var check = document.getElementById["display"].value;
        var check1 = document.getElementById["display1"].value;

        if(check){
            document.getElementById("display").style.display = "block";
            return true;
        }
        else{
            if(check1){
                document.getElementById("display1").style.display = "block"
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
```

I have the function on the submit button:

```
 <input type="button" onClick="return checkTextField(); SubmitMe();" value="Submit">&nbsp;&nbsp;
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Any assistance would be appreciated.

**UPDATE:** I have the following that checks if the values are empty:

```
if (document.HPlanLookup.txtSearch.value=="") {
  alert("Please enter the HPCODE.")
  document.HPlanLookup.txtSearch.focus()
  return false
}
```

Which works if user has not inputed or selected any value:

I have the following if that checks if it is not empty and to see:

```
 if(document.HPlanLookup.txtSearch.value!="" && document.getElementById("HPCODE").click == true){
        checkTextField()
    }
```

The following function just removes the hidden portion:

```
function checkTextField() {
    document.getElementById("display").style.display = "block";
}
```

The info does appear for a moment and then disappears. What do I need to do to leave it display after user submits and how can i achieve this when user inputs a value?

Comment: You are not checking until the form is submitted.  That's probably too late.

Comment: @DanBracuk Okay, where would determine where I should check if the user has manually entered value or has selected the magnifying glass?

Comment: In the onblur events of the appropriate form fields.

Comment: @Dan Bracuk: Okay. But how would I distinguish between a user manual input and a selection from a dropdown? I am having a hard time to distinguish either or and have the hidden tr tags to appear accordingly

Comment: To troubleshoot you checkTextField() function, start by looking at the values of check and check1.

Comment: @DanBracuk: Okay so I did your suggestion. I was able for a moment to have a hidden tr to display. However, when the second portion of the code displays the rest of the results, it disappears again. My guess I do not change the display css.